# Primefaces Datatable does not update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I add a row from "Create.jsf" page and I go to "List.jsf" to see the datatable I get the same result before adding the row.
I have two solutions : 
1 - I must clean browser cache everytime I want to see the new row or add a button to update the datatable.
Or I change the Controller from SessionScope to RequestScope (it works but it's not a good idea because it takes a lot of time to load the list everytime).

any other solution please ?

Thank you :)

Comment: how about to use something like `update="idOfTable"` in your `p:commandButton` ?

Comment: Can you paste your code here? Also: try to paginate your table, should reduce load times. Making your "controller" Session scope sounds bad, how about `@ViewScoped` ???